# Rails integration test don't see routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing because I recently added a two-step authorization to active_admin in my application using the gem: 'devise-two-factor'. Everything is working, unfortunately when I started to write tests I noticed that the paths I added do not exist in the test environment (there is an error). What is the reason for this and how to fix it. thanks in advance for your help.

Error:

```
 test_can_setup_2FA_for_admin_user                              ERROR (325.99s)
    Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/admin/admin_users/6/edit_two_factor"
                test/controllers/admin/sessions_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:AdminUsersControllerTest>'
Finished in 325.99535s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
[SlowTest] AdminUsersControllerTest#test_can_setup_2FA_for_admin_user : 325.99s
```

routes:

```
rails routes | grep edit_two_factor


                       edit_two_factor_authentication_confirmation GET      /two_factor_authentication/confirmation/edit(.:format)                                                             two_factor_authentication/confirmations#edit {:host=>"571e-77-222-242-230.eu.ngrok.io"}
                      edit_two_factor_authentication_recovery_code GET      /two_factor_authentication/recovery_codes/:id/edit(.:format)                                                       two_factor_authentication/recovery_codes#edit {:host=>"571e-77-222-242-230.eu.ngrok.io"}
                                    edit_two_factor_authentication GET      /two_factor_authentication/edit(.:format)                                                                          two_factor_authentications#edit {:host=>"571e-77-222-242-230.eu.ngrok.io"}
                                  edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user GET      /admin/admin_users/:id/edit_two_factor(.:format)                                                                   admin/admin_users#edit_two_factor {:host=>"571e-77-222-242-230.eu.ngrok.io"}
```

test code:

```
class AdminUsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'can setup 2FA for admin user' do
    admin_user = create(:admin_user)
    get edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user_path(admin_user)

    assert_template 'admin/admin_users/show_two_factor'
  end
end
```

RAILS_ENV=test rails routes | grep edit_two_factor

```
               edit_two_factor_authentication_confirmation GET      /two_factor_authentication/confirmation/edit(.:format)                                                             two_factor_authentication/confirmations#edit {:host=>"prograils.io"}
              edit_two_factor_authentication_recovery_code GET      /two_factor_authentication/recovery_codes/:id/edit(.:format)                                                       two_factor_authentication/recovery_codes#edit {:host=>"prograils.io"}
                            edit_two_factor_authentication GET      /two_factor_authentication/edit(.:format)                                                                          two_factor_authentications#edit {:host=>"prograils.io"}
                          edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user GET      /admin/admin_users/:id/edit_two_factor(.:format)                                                                   admin/admin_users#edit_two_factor {:host=>"prograils.io"}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Can you run a `RAILS_ENV=test rails routes` and see what appears in that list?

Comment: check your Gemfile and see if `devise-two-factor` gem is added in any group or is outside. if it's inside a group and `test` environment is not part of the list, you need to update your Gemfile. it would be best if you ideally kept this gem outside of any grouping as this gem should be available for all the environments.

Comment: It is interesting that it sees the path helper though as it has clearly identified `edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user_path(admin_user)` means "/admin/admin_users/6/edit_two_factor"

Comment: @SachinSingh `devise-two-factor` is outside in gemfile

Comment: I mange to resolve the problem. I change `edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user_path` to `edit_two_factor_admin_admin_user_url` idk why `path` don't work